# How can I change the default table name format in AWS Glue catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

In glue data catalog the default table name for any table is coming like **DatabaseName_SchemaName_TableName**.
Is there a way to change it? just like I want only the table name in the name of table.
I mean if the table name in source is **TEST** then in glue catalog it should be **TEST**.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: Hi Robert, Just like we load the schema definition in glue database from Postgres RDS. The default name is like DATABASENAME_SCHEMANAME_TABLENAME. So I read many documents and found there is no way to change it. Correct na?